# How to load jpeg picture from directory

Tags: r, image-processing

I'm trying to load and plot a picture from that path :

```
C:\Users\Rayane_2\Desktop\Data\PCB-DATASET-master\PCB-DATASET-master\01_missing_hole_01.jpeg
```

I tried :

```
library(imager)
file <- system.file('C:\Users\Rayane_2\Desktop\Data\PCB-DATASET-master\PCB-DATASET-master\01_missing_hole_01.jpeg',package='imager')
im <- load.image(file)
im # file not found
```

Example of correct run provided by the package :

```
library(imager)
file <- system.file('extdata/parrots.png',package='imager')
#system.file gives the full path for a file that ships with a R package
#if you already have the full path to the file you want to load just run:
#im <- load.image("/somedirectory/myfile.png")
im <- load.image(file)
plot(im) #Parrots!
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: (1) Directory backslashes (windows) must be escaped always, so `"C:\\Users\\Rayane_2\\..."`. Even on windows, though, you can use forward slashes as in `"C:/Users/Rayane_2/..."`, many find the double-backslashes visually displeasing. (2) `system.file` looks for files *within a package*, not in general. There is no file named `"C:\\Users\\...\\01_missing_hole_01.jpg"` in any package. Either use `load.image("C:\\Users\\...\01_missing_hole_01.jpg")`.

Comment: From [`?system.file`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.file.html), that function is intended to find *"the full file names of files in packages "*.

Comment: I need to load from a file directory found in desktop

Comment: See my answer. Bottom line, stop using `system.file` for this, it's the wrong function for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Backslashes as directory delimiters *must be escaped*, you should have seen the error

   ```r
   Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
   ```

   Escape it with another backslash, as in

   ```r
   'C:\\Users\\Rayane_2\\Desktop\\Data\\PCB-DATASET-master\\PCB-DATASET-master\\01_missing_hole_01.jpeg'
   ```

   Even on windows, though, one can use forward-slashes, so this also works:

   ```r
   'C:/Users/Rayane_2/Desktop/Data/PCB-DATASET-master/PCB-DATASET-master/01_missing_hole_01.jpeg'
   ```
2. `system.file` only finds files *within packages*. From [`?system.file`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.file.html):

   ```
   Description

       Finds the full file names of files in packages etc.


   Arguments
       ...: character vectors, specifying subdirectory and file(s) within
            some package.  The default, none, returns the root of the
            package.  Wildcards are not supported.
   ```

   This means that all paths provided in the `...` arguments need to be relative. One such example is what you put in your question,

   ```r
   system.file('extdata/parrots.png',package='imager')
   ```

   If you look at the file structure of the installed package (perhaps `C:/Users/Rayane_2/R/win_library/4.1/imager`), you'll see directories named `Meta`, `R`, `data`, `doc`, `help`, `html`, and (not found in every package) `extdata`. In that directory must be `parrots.png`. If a file is found within the specified package's installation directory, then the full (absolute) path of the file you seek is returned.

   The *value* of `system.file` is that you may not know the full path. This is a good method when (1) doing something programmatically where other users will be using your code; (2) you have multiple library paths in `.libPaths()` and don't know which one contains the package, and you don't want to check all of them yourself; or (3) you want shorter and more self-documenting code.

   If you already know the full path of a file, then `system.file` doesn't help.

   Bottom line, `system.file` is the wrong function for this.
3. Just load the file directly.

   ```r
   library(imager)
   im <- load.image('C:/Users/Rayane_2/Desktop/Data/PCB-DATASET-master/PCB-DATASET-master/01_missing_hole_01.jpeg')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these.

For more info see `?Quotes`, `?file.path`, `?Sys.getenv`, `?path.expand`.  The `path.expand` example will depend on how your home directory is set but typically it has been set to `C:\Users\yourname\Documents` .

```
file.path("C:", "Users", "Rayane_2", "Desktop", "Data", "PCB-DATASET-master",
  "PCB-DATASET-master", "01_missing_hole_01.jpeg")

file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "Desktop", "Data", "PCB-DATASET-master",
  "PCB-DATASET-master", "01_missing_hole_01.jpeg")

r"{C:\Users\Rayane_2\Desktop\Data\PCB-DATASET-master\PCB-DATASET-master\01_missing_hole_01.jpeg}"

"C:\\Users\\Rayane_2\\Desktop\\Data\\PCB-DATASET-master\\PCB-DATASET-master\\01_missing_hole_01.jpeg"

# this depends on how your home variable has been set but the
#   setting is often such that this works
path.expand("~\\..\\Desktop\\Data\\PCB-DATASET-master\\PCB-DATASET-master\\01_missing_hole_01.jpeg")

"C:/Users/Rayane_2/Desktop/Data/PCB-DATASET-master/PCB-DATASET-master/01_missing_hole_01.jpeg"

# after entering this navigate to file. This will display the path
#   to the file and you can then copy and paste it from the 
#   R console into your code.
file.choose()
```